# JIRA: Any way to compare summed up estimates for one release to available time?

Tags: jira

the customer I'm working for uses JIRA. However since they have a big Enterprise license (~2k users) they will not sign off additional plugins that would only be used by a comparatively small amount of users.

However, we in lead development have to present a few figures that we have to assemble manually at the moment. We are supposed to be able to always tell for one release how many hours are already "booked". (Original) Estimates are added reliably to all issues and everything is assigned to exactly one release. Based on the amount of workers in the team I can calculate the number of hours we have for the next release.

Is there any built-in possibility to do a report for this at any time? I'm a bit lost at the moment since I wonder where I'd store or how I'd calculate the amount of hours.

Note: we're not allowed to buy plugins, but we have coders at our fingertips. :D So a hint on how to script or code this would be appreciated as well.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest approach is to use JIRA REST API to extract the info you need. So this is task for your coders :-).

Please take a look on search method: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2450

I think that you can start with request like

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=fixVersion=YOUR_RELEASE
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, we already use the REST API to get and push data for our Gerrit server. So do you mean to do a REST API call from within Jira to do this? Or did you mean to do this call from an external script?

Today I checked Script Runner and found a lot of options there that help me with aggregating such data.